# Block scope in ruby

Tags: ruby, scope, variable-assignment, block

My understanding was that ruby blocks have block scope, and all variables created inside block will live only within the block.

**Example case:**

```
 food = ['toast', 'cheese', 'wine']
 food.each { |food| puts food.capitalize}
 puts food
```

**Output:**

```
"Toast"
"Cheese"
"Wine"
"Wine"
```

If you take the `food` variable inside the block (Each block), my understanding was that it has block scope. It lives only within the block scope, and does not have any influence on the outer variable `food`.

But the behavior is different, the outer variable named `food` is modified in this case. Is this understanding correct, In ruby do we have block scope?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is expected behaviour for ruby 1.8. [It was fixed](http://ruby.about.com/b/2009/02/02/using-new-features-in-ruby-191-block-variable-scope.htm) [in 1.9](http://www.igvita.com/2011/02/03/new-ruby-19-features-tips-tricks/). Snippets below are run with ruby 1.9.3

```
food = ['toast', 'cheese', 'wine']
food.each { |food| puts food.capitalize.inspect} # !> shadowing outer local variable - food
puts food.inspect
# >> "Toast"
# >> "Cheese"
# >> "Wine"
# >> ["toast", "cheese", "wine"]
```

You are correct, `food` from the block is scoped to that block and shadows other variables with this name. But if you do something destructive to it, it will be reflected in the original array, because it is reference to array element, not its copy. Observe:

```
food = ['toast', 'cheese', 'wine']

food.each { |f| f.capitalize} # transform and discard
food # => ["toast", "cheese", "wine"]

food.each { |f| f.capitalize! } # transform destructively (bang-version)
food # => ["Toast", "Cheese", "Wine"]
```

Comment: I use ruby version 1.8.7. I do not get the result you have mentioned in your response. Is this a bug?

Comment: I use 1.9.3. Let me try in 1.8.7

Comment: I understand that the food variable is shadowed inside the block, so its a different variable than the outer one. When i do not use any destructive update (i am not using bang-version), why does it update the outer variable?

Comment: It should not. Hold on, I'm installing 1.8.7. By the way, why don't you upgrade? Support for 1.8.7 will be dropped in next rails.

Comment: Yes, apparently, this is the expected behaviour in ruby 1.8. [A blog post](http://jamescrisp.org/2010/10/23/ruby-scoping-and-blocks/).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm a bit confused about what's going on here. The unexpected part about OP's output in 1.8 was that the final `"Wine"` was capitalised, since the `capitalise` method being invoked is non destructive. Even if the `food` variable holding an array is overwritten by the `food` parameter, why is the final value of the parameter `"Wine"`, and not `"wine"`?

Comment: @Asad: off the top of my head, I don't know. And frankly, I don't want to know. 1.8 is dead.

Answer (score 4):

The block inherits the scope from the context it is defined in. Take a look at this example:

```
def give_me_a_proc
  test = "foo"
  lambda { puts test }
end

test = "bar"
give_me_a_proc.call

# => "foo"
```

So it doesn't matter where the proc/block is executed, but rather where it was defined.

In your case the `food` variable inside the block is indeed shadowing the `food` array from outside. But you really operate on the actual elements (not duplicates/clones) of `food` array in the block so any changes to them will be reflected outside.

The reason why `food` array changes into `"Wine"` string after the block is finished is that the block operates in the same scope the `food` array was defined, so it overwrites it with the last element of the array since it is the last object that is assigned to `food` variable.

Comment: The question was (I guess) why the shadowing persists after `each` is over.

Comment: for the same reason: you operate in the context the block is defined in, so you can overwrite variables there. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Anyway, ruby 1.9 behaves correctly. It does not overwrite names from outer scope (in case of block parameters).

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in Ruby 1.9

```
food = ['toast', 'cheese', 'wine']
food.each { |food| puts food.capitalize }
puts food # ["toast", "cheese", "wine"]
```

I think if you want to use local variable in Ruby 1.8, try `lambda` (Sorry, I don't install Ruby 1.8, so can't test it, but work in 1.9)

```
food = ['toast', 'cheese', 'wine']
lambda do |food|
    food.each {|food| puts food.capitalize}
end.call(food)
puts food # ["toast", "cheese", "wine"]
```