# Why do I get an infinite loop in my ruby script?

Tags: ruby

According to the description, the operator `||=` will assign values ​​only once, but it looks like it does it every time and we have an infinite loop. (using Ruby 2.6.6p146)

```
loop do
  fib ||= [0,1]
  p fib
  i = fib[-1] + fib[-2]
  break if i >= 100
  fib << i
  p fib
end

# [0, 1]
# [0, 1, 1]
# [0, 1]
# [0, 1, 1]
# [0, 1]
# [0, 1, 1]
# ...
```

Comment: `fib` goes out of scope at the end of the block on each iteration, so it will be `nil` on the next. Put `fib = [0, 1]` _before_ the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your `loop do ... end` creates a new [block scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685965/block-scope-in-ruby).

The behavior is different if you have an *outer* variable `fib`:

```
fib = nil
loop do
  # ... your stuff here
end
```

In that case, calling `fib ||=` in the block would change the outer `fib` variable (because it's in the outer scope).

But since you have no outer variable `fib`, each time your loop block runs, `fib` is undefined again.